# Visual Studio server explorer showing only 5000 tables

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, server-explorer

I'm currently using visual studio 2013 and conntecting to oracle DB using the server explorer. Its only showing me the top 5000 tables. Where can i change the number of tables that visual studio displays ?

Here is the screenshot of the message.[image]

Comment: That's a LOT of tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Figured it out :

If we go to tools> Options > Oracle Developer Tools>DataConnections

[image]

But Unfortunately 5000 is the maximum number of objects that we can see. :(